# Is asking about a player on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Is asking about a player on topic here?

E.g.

- [Who is Sikander Raja?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2971/540)
- Who is Cheteshwar Pujara? Tell me about him in detail.
- etc...

IMO it shouldn't be on topic. Because we can have infinite number of questions like:
Who is Sachin Tendulkar?, Who is Lionel Messi? etc.

Comment: I don't like question *Who is Lionel Messi?* (Such questions might be closed as overly broad.) But a question *Is it true that Lionel Messi scored at least one goal for 66 consecutive matches?* would by IMO ok.

Comment: @Martin Why would *Is it true that Lionel Messi scored at least one goal for 66 consecutive matches?* be ok? The answer is "true" or "false." What additional value or usefulness does that question provide?

Comment: No. What value or usefulness does asking who a player is have?

Comment: @edmastermind29 Asking *Who is Lionell Messi*? falls under [closure reason](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions): "too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many of valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format". Asking for some specific interesting fact about a player is different from that. The [Zidane question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/was-zinedine-zidane-ever-caught-offside) is an example of such question and sparked no discussion whether such question was on-topic.

Comment: @Martin One occurrence in a career seems to be far more significant than 66. Also, if you asked your question that way, I would assume the answer is true. "Too broad" makes sense because "Who is Lionel Messi?" opens up the entire book, many answers debate.

Comment: @Martin How about, "Which player holds the longest streak for scoring at least one goal?" (Not sure) Answer: Lionel Messi with 66. Trivial, yes, but makes the question more useful than just plainly asking if it is true that Lionel Messi has had scored at least one goal for 66 consecutive matches.

Comment: @edmastermind29 I highly doubt that [the answer would be yes](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Lionel+Messi%22+%22consecutive+games%22). Anyway, you are making more-or-less the same point as me (with a better chosen example, I have to admit), that asking about specific player is ok, if question is not too broad.

Comment: @Martin Then why ask a true/false question in the first place? All I am trying to say is that the wording and scope could be improved...instead of asking about a **specific** player, which is very narrow in subject matter and rarely useful. Q: Has Babe Ruth hit a Home Run in his career? A: Yes. 714 home runs to be exact. This question is blasphemous in a historical context...and the question "Who holds the record for the most Home Runs in history? would be better to ask.

Answer (score 3):

No. The problem doesn't inherently lie in the possibility of having an "infinite number of questions" (which is a good problem to have), but lies in the narrow subject matter, wide scope, and low potential of usefulness these questions (in the forms above) present.

1) Asking about a specific player narrows the subject matter to one participant in any given sport. This represents a question that is rarely likely to be useful.

Alternative: Perhaps there is a specific technique utilized by a given player that makes him/her successful that can be captured and analyzed. This kind of question, which would not be about the player but about the technique, would be on-topic here as it would be useful to participants.

**What does [player X] do that contributes to his high-percentage in converting penalty kicks?**

2) Requesting information on a specific player (eg, Who is Lionel Messi?) is too broad (wide scope) and a research request. What about Lionel Messi do you want to know?

Alternative: If you want to know about a specific technique utilized by Lionel Messi, that would be a technique question and would be useful to participants.

**How does Lionel Messi curve or bend the ball so sharply?**

---

In response to comments above, a question like, "Is it true that Lionel Messi scored at least one goal for 66 consecutive matches?" cripples the scope and potential usefulness of such a question even further. The answer is either true or false. If false, the difference would be in the number of consecutive matches.

Alternative: Ask the trivia question, **"Which player holds the longest streak for scoring at least one goal?"**